# Dynamic routing from database data

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I'm thinking to implement a small cms just for the fun of it, and what I'd like is for the user to be able to create sites and pages from the cms.

For example there will be some form asking the user for a "site" name and under that site the user will be able to create a site tree of n levels deep which will get saved in a db.

ex: "blah/article", "blah/blah/blah/article".

My issue is how would I implement such routing in expressjs?
How can I declare my routes dynamically based on what the user has created and per site?

If for example I have 2 sites: site1 and site2.

localhost:3000/site1/somepathhere/blah/blah

localhost:3000/site2/someotherpathhere/blah/blah/blah

I want routes for each site to be dynamic (no idea what the user will create) and I want each site routes to apply to that site only and not globally.

So far I playing around with some code but I'm not sure if there is some better way to achieve this.

```
app.param('site', function(req, res, next, site) {
    req.site = site;
    next();
});


app.get('/:site', function(req, res) {

    res.send(req.site + "<br><pre>" + JSON.stringify(req.params, null, 4) + "</pre>");

});

app.get('/:site/*', function(req, res) {

    res.send(req.site + "<br><pre>" + JSON.stringify(req.params, null, 4) + "</pre>");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

express routing,essentially is playing(parsing and analyzing) with strings. you can implement an url parser that will take the routes you read from database.